# Why CSS of my wordpress page in IE does not work properly but when applied to a non wordpress static page works fine in IE?

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have created a 4 section page website where one of the links is about the "news" and is dynamic. As you know I had to create a custom theme of my original design into wordpress so that I can implement it. CSS works fine across all browsers both on static webpages and the on the single wordpress one. However when it comes to Internet Explorer 10 something strange happens. CSS on static pages works perfect but when I click on the wordpress dynamic page I have a problem. Navigation links are not highlighted and drop down menu does not respond at all. This happens only in IE, but it gets crazy because it is not a general problem, it only happens when I am on that single dynamic page of wordpress (the rest web pages work fine with the same CSS). I do not know what s my error because the same wordpress page works fine on Safari, Firefox and Chrome! I hope you understand what I am saying because it s a bit complicated.

If you need any further code snippets or screenshots please let me know. The reason I did not post a link to the website is that it is in greek and you won't have a clue where to click.

Thanks for taking the time to read it.

Comment: Can you send a link to the page that works and the page that doesnt work.  Then we wont need to click but can see what is happening

Comment: http://stelioshadjiperis.com/Synchrono/wordpress/

Try this in IE and then with Firefox or Chrome. But When you are viewing it in IE click on the rest links too to see that CSS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is out of whack.

You have

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>My Website | Just another WordPress site</title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://stelioshadjiperis.com/Synchrono/wordpress/wp-content/themes/synchrono/style.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://stelioshadjiperis.com/Synchrono/wordpress/xmlrpc.php" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://stelioshadjiperis.com/Synchrono/wordpress/wp-content/themes/synchrono/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://stelioshadjiperis.com/Synchrono/wordpress/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://stelioshadjiperis.com/Synchrono/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.6.1" />

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
```

The DOCTYPE, HTML, and HEAD tags needs to come first.  In Firefox and Chrome it is fixing it for you, IE is forcing you to fix it yourself.

For future help valdiate your code at http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I corrected it, css still does not work properly. It s my first website so I have a lot to learn yet.

Comment: I just hard refreshed and viewing source and it is still not right

http://stelioshadjiperis.com/Synchrono/wordpress/

Hit F12, brings up IE developer mode, you will see you are in quirks mode, this is because your code is still not in proper order.
Right Click View Source in the Main window and you will see how your Doctype and the other tags are out of order.

Comment: I also have to ask, why are you mixing a static site with wordress.  Wordpress can do all you need to do, so why mix it?

Comment: Yes your right, it s my mistake, even when I fix it and save it on the remote server it s not updated, I do it via dreamweaver CS6. Hopefully I ll fix it.

Comment: When I started designing the website I had no idea of how wordpress works at all. I did not want to start with something blindly. You know I learned the traditional way when I was on University. To be honest I had not decided whether I would include a dynamic page for the "news" or not. So when I said I would it seemed a lot of work (almost impossible) to write my own CMS, SQL and PHP. Having completed most part of the website I started looking into wordpress and that s how I ended up like that. In the near future I will try to bring this completely into wordpress but I am still a beginner.

Comment: You are right it works! Of course you were right :D

Comment: Looks like you fixed it.

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer :)  good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been trying to discover this "bug" for 3 days. No possibility of me realising that the error would be in the HTML file. Thanks once again. First time here too, how do I accept yours as an answer?

Comment: Should be to the left a check box to accept the answer, underneath the up and down arrows.  Been awhile since I accepted answers so not sure exactly where it is these days.